# Log Activity in Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

In accordance with Title.

How to separate the date and make the time on one line??
For Example, I have problem with this
https://prnt.sc/vb7izv

This my script

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_overview">
                      <div class="timed-activities padded">
                        @if(count((array)$activitys))
                        @foreach($activitys as $activity)
                        <div class="timed-activity">
                          <div class="ta-date">
                            <span>{{date("j M Y",strtotime($activity->created_at))}}</span>
                          </div>
                          <div class="ta-record-w">
                            <div class="ta-record">
                              <div class="ta-timestamp">
                                <strong>{{date("H:i",strtotime($activity->created_at))}}</strong>
                              </div>
                              <div class="ta-activity">
                                {!! $activity->description !!}
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        @endforeach
                        @else
                        <h4 class="text-center">
                            No Have Activity
                        </h4>
                        @endif
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

I want to this https://prnt.sc/vb7og7

Thankyou

Comment: It would be best if you post your scripts here rather then using a pic

Comment: @StevenPss I think so, but It took a long time to explain from the start, sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I Research, I found this solved 
For Documentation, I will share it.

For Example:

**Controller**

```
public function show(){
        $activitys= Activity::whereCauser_id($user->id)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get()
        ->groupby(function ($date) {
            return Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format('d M Y');
        });
   return view('example',compact('activitys'));
}
```

After it, you need make View blade like this
**View Blade**

```
              <div class="timed-activities padded">
                     @if(count((array)$activitys))
                        @foreach($activitys as $activitydate => $activitygroup)
                        <div class="timed-activity">
                          <div class="ta-date">
                            <span>{{$activitydate}}</span>
                          </div>
                          <div class="ta-record-w">
                            @foreach($activitygroup as $activity)
                            <div class="ta-record">
                              <div class="ta-timestamp">
                                <strong>{{date("H:i",strtotime($activity->created_at))}}</strong>
                              </div>
                              <div class="ta-activity">
                                {!! $activity->description !!}
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            @endforeach
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        @endforeach
                        @else
                        <h4 class="text-center">
                            No Have Activity
                        </h4>
                        @endif
                  </div>
```